# Transforming boolean logic to 2 clause at a time in AND/OR

Tags: javascript, java, sql, arrays, transformation

Apologies for the awkward title, I couldn't come up with something better.

I have boolean logic strings like

`AND(
    column.contains.5,
    column.contains.6,
    OR(
        column.equal.1,
        column.equal.2,
        column.equal.3,
        AND(
            column.contains.7,
            column.contains.8
        )
    ),
    column.contains.4
)`

**The problem is** the script that parses this only accepts two clauses at a time in the AND/OR. i.e. AND(condition1, condition2) but not AND(cond1, cond2, cond3). This means anything that has more than 2 conditions needs to be transformed appropriately so only two conditions are passed in. How could I do this? (working to fix the shortcoming, but need a temp solution)

**My current thinking is** to take that string, convert it into an array with the 0th element being the operator (`["AND", column.contains.5, column.contains6, ["OR", [column.equal.1], [column.equal.2], [column.equal.3], ["AND", column.contains.7, column.contains.8]], column.contains.4]`). Then any time an array has more than 3 elements, I would recursively break conditions 2 to n down until it's always 2 clauses. Does that seem correct?

**Or is there a better way?**

Desired output from the input I gave would be (preserves the logic):

`AND(
    column.contains.5,
    AND (
        column.contains.6,
        AND (
            OR(
                column.equal.1,
                OR (
                    column.equal.2,
                    OR (
                        column.equal.3,
                        AND(
                            column.contains.7,
                            column.contains.8
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            column.contains.4
        )
    )
)`

Comment: Your approach is probably best. The only other way I can think to do it is to create a new parser, but it seems like that might not be possible.